# .NET Batch on-premises?

Tags: .net, azure, batch-processing

I am in need for a .Net batch framework (similar to Java Spring Batch) which provides an API for starting bathes, is able to partition batch tasks to several worker nodes, and support pausing/resuming of batch runs, etc.

This is a very common requirement for enterprise applications, but I have yet to find a complete batch framework like that of Spring Batch.

I stumbled upon .NET Batch namespaces, and it is apparently somehow related to Azure. Can these libraries be used on-premises? Do I still need to build the actual engine myself?

Comment: azure batch services works for process intensive jobs that run uninterrupted and is scalable. It is purely for azure cloud.  For an on premises scenario you can look at windows workflow or thrid party services like JAMS, Hangfire etc

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source .Net Batch Framework based upon the Spring Batch specification ( JSR 352 ) that is available on nugget and Github   :

https://github.com/SummerBatch

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SummerBatch/

It also enables partitionning batch through configuration :

```
<step id="testStep">
    …
    <partition>
        <mapper ref="testPartitioner" grid-size="10" />
    </partition>
</step>
```

Restarting a failed batch to a the beginning of the failed transaction is supported as well